# Can I use Gmail's API with just Javascript but without using my personal API Key and User ID?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I am worried that if I publish a webpage with my API Key and User ID in the javascript code, then it might get used a ton and make so many requests that I end up getting charged for going over their request limit.
So instead I am having the user enter their own API Key and User ID credentials to use the webpage. But it seems like there should be a way for the user to just click an "Authorize" button and have it create some temporary credentials for them.

I think what I am looking for is an "access-token" but I can't find a way to generate that with just javascript.

```
gapi.client.init({
  'apiKey':   'User API Key Here',
  'clientId': 'User Client ID Here',
  'discoveryDocs': ['https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'],
  'scope': 'profile',
}).then(function() { ... }
```

Comment: AFAIK, that is not possible (if and only if it work, then you'll be the one that will not be able the check the traffic request). My advise is that use the restriction parameter when creating API keys and client IDs, this way only authorized javascript origins will be able to use your credentials. See image as [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xi7A.png).

Comment: That's what I figured. I was hoping there would be a way to open it up to everybody without using my credentials because even if I restrict the origin to only my page, people would be able to use it until my request limit is reached or exceeded. I guess I would have to use the serverside authentication to achieve this result, right?